# reduce the top margin of the abstract

Tags: margins, abstract

How can I reduce the top margin of the abstract?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{title title title title title title title}
\author{Blah Blah}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[75]
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

I will use it for thesis:

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/mkzrzktcbzfl/clone

Comment: That template is based on `book` class, meaning there is no abstract available by default. Though the template provides an `abstract` environment, it has nothing to do with the example you have shown.

Comment: Maybe you want `\begin{abstract}[]` or `\begin{abstract}[\vspace*{2cm}]` or the global option `consistentlayout` .... who knows.

Comment: That being said, you are asking for a technique to peel an orange while you really want to peel an apple. Different things. The question is clear, but no answer will help you with that template. I wouldn't even use that template. -> https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Scientific_Reports

Comment: @Johannes_B, you are right. Their solution did not work for me. Your proposed `\begin{abstract}[\vspace*{2cm}]` adjusts the gap between abstract title and abstract content. But I want to bring up both.

Comment: Use my first suggestion (with the completely empty brackets). What do you see? Can you provide a screenshot? Can you provide an example that represents your question instead of some completely unrelated code?

Comment: Is there any news here? The question as posted in its entirety is unclear.

Answer (score 3):

This is a little hackish, but you can use the [titling](https://ctan.org/pkg/titling?lang=en) package to remove the space after the date, in effect reducing the abstract's top margin:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titling} % we need this for the \postdate tag

\title{title title title title title title title}
\author{Blah Blah}
% The line below removes 1em of space directly below the date,
% which here is also directly above the abstract
\postdate{\end{center}\vspace*{-1em}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[75]
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

You may notice that some other vertical spacing regarding the title matter is affected somewhat by using the titling package, but the good thing about it is every aspect of this spacing is easily customizable; e.g.,

```
\setlength{\droptitle}{-1em}
```

will raise all of the title matter vertically by `1em`; similar commands can be found for pretty much any part of the title material.

Comment: Thanks very much. Do you mean `\setlength{\droptitle}{-1em}` reset everything to the default?

Comment: Not quite -- that just affects where vertically on the page the title matter starts. Other commands such as `\preauthor{}` etc. will govern everything else. That's why I recommend the `titling` package; if you're wanting to customize the abstract spacing, you may want to customize other aspects as well.

Comment: I am afraid of affecting the other chapters

Comment: @ar2015 That should just work on the title/abstract and nothing else.

Comment: Hi duckmayr, don't bother. The OP uses a template that has nothing to do with the posted code. Any solution that will work with the MWE won't work with the template.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty hack:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{title title title title title title title}
\author{Blah Blah}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\vspace*{-1cm}
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[75]
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: and how to reset to the defaults after?

Comment: @ar2015 This does not effect anything after, just a bit of negative space in front of the abstract.

Comment: Sam, don't bother. The OP uses a template that has nothing to do with the posted code. Any solution that will work with the MWE won't work with the template. Nevertheless, +1 from my side :-)

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks for the warning and the vote :)